# multiplate RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I developing my app in which I use `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`.
And in adapter I want use multiple `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` in which different data.

**MainActivity**

```
adapter = new RVAdapter(realm.where(QuoteObject.class).findAll(), this);
```

**But from another fragment i need give another data:**

```
adapter = new RVAdapter(realm.where(AuthorObject.class).findAll(), this);
```

**My Adapter**

```
class RVAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<QuoteObject, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "###" + "RVAdapter";


private Context context;
private CustomGridLayoutManager customGridLayoutManager;

RVAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<QuoteObject> quotes, Context context) {
    super(quotes, true);
    this.context = context;
    customGridLayoutManager = new CustomGridLayoutManager(context);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            View quoteView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_of_quote, viewGroup, false);
            return new AllQuotesViewHolder(quoteView);
        case 1:
            View topicView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_of_topic, viewGroup, false);
            return new TopicViewHolder(topicView);
        case 2:
            View authorView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_of_author, viewGroup, false);
            return new AuthorViewHolder(authorView);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()){
        case 0:
           final AllQuotesViewHolder allQuotesViewHolder = (AllQuotesViewHolder) viewHolder;
            break;
        case 1:
            final AuthorViewHolder authorViewHolder = (AuthorViewHolder) viewHolder;
            break;
        case 2:
            final TopicViewHolder topicViewHolder = (TopicViewHolder) viewHolder;
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getData().size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2 * 2;
}

private class AllQuotesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;
    TextView contentOfQuote, authorQuote;
    ImageButton btnViewComment, btnShareQuote, btnSetLike;
    TextView amountLikes;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    AllQuotesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        this.contentOfQuote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentOfQuote);
        this.authorQuote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.authorQuote);
        this.btnViewComment = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnViewComment);
        this.btnShareQuote = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnShareQuote);
        this.btnSetLike = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnSetLike);
        this.amountLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.amountLike);
        this.progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_progress_bar);
    }
}

private class TopicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;

    TopicViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }

}

private class AuthorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;

    AuthorViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }

}
```

}

How do I transfer different data to one `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`?

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for the concept behind https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates but you'll need to replace `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<QuoteObject` with `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<? extends RealmObject`